# Regex for Google Analytics to only display strings that contain a special character somewhere

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm trying to filter in Google Analytics using Regex to find all results which contain any special character.

I am filtering for anchor text in a Google Analytics event, rather than URL paths.

By special characters I mean anything at all that is not a number or upper/lowercase standard letters. This would also capture things like accented characters for other languages. At least one character will be either a-zA-Z0-9.

The expression needs to capture anything containing one or more 'special character' (based on my definition above of special character)

**Example**

- Hello (do not show)
- hi£%there (show)
- Shouldn't (show)
- 99redballoons (do not show)

I have tried the following with no success, and think it's quite far off... Any help appreciated

`/^[a-zA-Z0-9]$/`

Comment: You might need to define "special character". Do you mean symbols, character that need more than 7 bits to represent in Unicode. Characters that can be upper or lower cased or what?

Comment: Also, should there be at least a single `[a-zA-Z0-9]` present. Are 1 or more special chars also valid? https://regex101.com/r/TurWfH/1

Comment: Good point, I have clarified in main post, basically anything that isn't upper/lower case normal alphabet and 0-9.

The suggestion above only seems to work if you have a list of every special character. I want to capture anything that someone might type, so accents on letters, punctuation marks etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting this into the regex match field

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9]
```

or if you want to get rid of spaces

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me there! Tweaked it to capture spaces, but remove things like tabs:

[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]